# How do I draw 2D fonts in processing P3D mode?

Tags: text, fonts, 3d, processing

I'm running a sketch with an array of points in 3D space (P3D). I'd like to add an interface to it by drawing text as if it were "onscreen"/2D, only using "X, Y" parameters.

When I tried just adding "text("!@#$%", width/2, height/2);" it rendered in 3D space.

Is it possible? I tried "textMode(SCREEN) but doesnt exist in processing 2 anymore.

Comment: "anymore?" Processing 2 is quite a few years old, Processing 3 is currently in public beta gearing up for release... The Processing 1.x API hasn't been valid for a *very* long time =)

Comment: lol I just got back to it, the one I had installed was still 1.x. I'll take a look on Processing 3 though, see if it has any solutions.

Comment: You'll have better luck if you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with your question. This can be just a simple sketch that shows a 3D point and your attempt to display text, so we can run it on our own machines to play with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found, I guess on the Processing Forum

You can use:

- a PMatrix3D for your 3D content
- and code your 2D stuff the plain old way

I wish it helps

```
    PMatrix3D baseMat;
    float alpha =0;

    void setup() {
      size(400, 400, P3D); 

      // Remember the start model view matrix values
      baseMat = getMatrix(baseMat);
    }

    void draw() {
      background(40);

      pushMatrix();
      camera(0, 0, 400, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
      directionalLight(255, 255, 255, -100, 150, -100);
      ambientLight(40, 40, 40);

      // 3D drawing stuff here
      rotateY(alpha);
      box(100);
      alpha += 0.05;
      popMatrix();

      // Restore the base matrix and lighting ready for 2D
      this.setMatrix(baseMat);
      ambientLight(255, 255, 255);

      // draw 2D stuff here
      rect(10, 10, 50, 10);
      textSize(25);
      text("voila", mouseX, mouseY);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that comes to mind is to create a 2D PGraphic that has the same width/height as your sketch, give it a transparent background, draw your text where you want on it, and then draw the PGraphic onto your real sketch like you would if you were copying over image source data.

Comment: thats a nice workaround but I need it to be dinamic :( (p.s.: need to show some variables, etc)

Comment: why would that not work? You create the PGraphic buffer globally, like say `PGraphic buffer`, then in setup you create it with the same size dimensions via `createGraphic` and then during drawing you can simply update the buffer, draw as image, next frame update the buffer, draw as image, repeat as long as your sketch runs